# Flask not activating function

Tags: python, testing, flask, html

I've been using python flask as well as html, in order to create a small website, (just as a hobby while I'm off school), I created a form in html, and saved it within the templates folder of the project. I also then added a function within the python script, so when a button is clicked of the webpage it would redirect the user back to the home page (index.html), however when I have tested the webpage and clicked on the button on the webpage (with the flask server running) a "400 bad request" page is shown

Python Code:

```
#Python code behind the website
import datetime
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, escape, request,    render_template
print ("started")
def Log(prefix, LogMessage):
    timeOfLog = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S" + " : ")
    logFile = open("Log.log", 'a')
    logFile.write("[" + timeOfLog + "][" + prefix + "][" + LogMessage + "] \n")
    logFile.close()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    print ("Acessed index")
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    text = request.form['text']#requests text from the text form
    processed_text = text #does nothing 
    user = "" #use poss in future to determin user
    logFile = open("MessageLog.msglog", 'a')#opens the message log file in append mode
    logFile.write(text + "\n")#stores the inputted message in the message log file
    logFile.close()
    #print (text)
    Log("User Message", (user + text))#uses the main log file to store messages aswell as errors
    print ("Accessing index")
    return render_template("test.html")

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    #text = request.form['text']
    print ("Test page function")
    #return "hello"
    return render_template("index.html") 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

HTML code:
    
    
    
        -->

```
<body>
<h1>Test Page</h1>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="my-form" value="Send">
</form>

</body>
```

Stack Track:
[image: stack trace]

Comment: Are you using `app.run(debug=True)`

Comment: Yes, the webpage still comes back as "400 Bad Request" no matter what state debug is in

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: started
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
started
Acessed index
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jul/2015 14:22:50] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jul/2015 14:22:51] "GET /static/js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404
 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jul/2015 14:22:51] "GET /static/css/grid.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jul/2015 14:22:51] "GET /static/css/sticky-footer.css HTTP/1.1
" 404 -

Comment: Please edit your question

Comment: That's also not a stack trace

Comment: AS it stands now with your code the only error I get is a `405: Method not allowed`

Comment: Then you did a `GET` instead of a `POST`.

Comment: What HTML file is that, `test.html` or `index.html`?

Comment: The file show in the post is the test.html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to post your form to the correct URL:

```
<body>
<h1>Test Page</h1>
<form method="POST" action='/test'>
    <input type="submit" name="my-form" value="Send">
</form>
</body>
```

By default if you don't add an `action` attribute to an HTML form it will just perform it's defined method to the URL you are currently on. You can add an `action` attribute to change that behavior.

You can also do this with the `url_for()` function. This is a bit safer as URL's tend to change more often than your view method names:

```
<body>
<h1>Test Page</h1>
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('test') }}">
    <input type="submit" name="my-form" value="Send">
</form>
</body>
```

You pass the name of the view method (not it's URL) as a string to the function. Be careful to use the right quotes.

Note that it's slightly confusing to have 2 views for the same URL. Usually something like this is done although YMMV but consider it for your application:

```
@app.route('/someurl')
def some_view():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # handle POST
    else:
        # handle GET
```